# SQL Server sp_send_dbmail prevent html encoding in body

Tags: html, sql-server, encoding, sp-send-dbmail

How can I prevent encoding within the body of an email sent using SQL Server's `sp_send_dbmail`?

Example:

```
EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail
     @recipients='my.email@somedomain.com',
     @subject = 'SQL email test',
     @body = 'this+that',
     @body_format = 'HTML'
```

The html source of the email that I receive looks like this:

```
this`&#43;`that
```

and the body looks fine:

```
this+that
```

However, what if I want the SOURCE to still have the + instead of the `&#43;` ?

Long back story on why I need to do this, but solving this would help me immensely. Is there a way to "escape" the + in my body parameter? Or any other idea on how to prevent this encoding?

Answer (score 0):

You can try doing a simple XML hack:

```
DECLARE @source VARCHAR(255) = 'this`&#43;`that';

DECLARE @body VARCHAR(255)= CAST ( CAST ( 'this`&#43;`that' AS XML ) AS VARCHAR(255) );
SELECT @body AS body;
```

Returns

```
+-------------+
|    body     |
+-------------+
| this`+`that |
+-------------+
```

This will not however remove your backticks. You can add a call to `REPLACE` if needed:

```
DECLARE @body VARCHAR(255)= REPLACE ( CAST ( CAST ( 'this`&#43;`that' AS XML ) AS VARCHAR(255) ), '`', '' );
```

Which results in:

```
+-----------+
|   body    |
+-----------+
| this+that |
+-----------+
```

Comment: So I tried this, but along the way I think I've discovered that something else is at work here. When I send the email, the string body shows what I want it to. When I receive the email in Outlook (and Windows 10 Mail), the + signs are getting encoded. In other browsers (Blue mail on android, web based email client from my ISP and a non-stock email client on iPhone) this is not happening.

Comment: It's possible there is some sort of filter doing this as a way of "protection." If it's email client specific, you may try searching for that client. Perhaps there's a setting for it.